# How can I filter an array of strings to detect valid URLs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have an array of string like this one :
['http://www.google.com','https://www.facebook.com','stackoverflow']

I want to filter it to take only the valid URLs?

I solve it in this way :

```
 var patternAbsoluteLinks = /^https?:\/\//i;
 var url = [];
 links.map(link => {
      if (patternAbsoluteLinks.test(link.getAttribute("href"))) {
        urls.push(link.getAttribute("href"));
      }
    });
```

How can I solve this in a more elegant way?
I tried using filter but it does not works :

```
const matchedSitesSuccess = links.filter(href =>
      patternAbsoluteLinks.test(link.getAttribute("href"))
    );
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your `filter` call you're having `href` as the parameter but use `link`: you probably want to name your parameter `link`, for a start...

Comment: What do you mean when saying the filter "does not work"? Does it throw an error, or return the wrong data? (And what is the error message or invalid data?)

Comment: find even integers: `[11,22,33,44,55].filter(/./.test, /[02468]$/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
const arr = ['http://www.google.com','https://www.facebook.com','stackoverflow'];

const isValidUrl = url => {
  const regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
  return regexp.test(url);
}

const validUrls = arr.filter(isValidUrl);
console.log(validUrls);
```